# Process details(CPU time, memory allocated) for a method in program

Tags: c#, .net, process

I want to calculate the **CPU time and the memory** allocated for a specific method in the whole program. I am able to get the CPU Time and the memory for the complete program. How to get the details for a specific method.

Also how to get the disk access the program made to the secondary storage while getting the values/information from the disk.

I tried to make the thread and make the method run by the created thread, but it didn't work. It is giving the information of the complete process. I am looking for a specific method.

Adding more details hope this helps in understanding the question.

*ok. i am writing a C# code*

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        **checkPoint_1_start**            
        //
        // Some code here
        //
        **checkPoint_2_start**

        calling_Method();

        **checkPoint_2_end**
        //
        // Some code here
        //

        **checkPoint_1_end**
    }

    public void calling_Method()
    {
        //
        //  Code of this method is very long and contains many variables.
        //  
    }
}
```

I am able to find the memory used from checkPoint_1_start to checkPoint_1_end. I want to how to find the memory used only between the checkPoint_2_start checkPoint_2_end.

I am using the below things to find the details of memory usage, it is giving for the entire process from checkPoint_1_start to checkPoint_1_end. How to get memory used between the checkPoint_2_start checkPoint_2_end.

*Private Memory: System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().PrivateMemorySize64 / 1024
Working set  Memory: System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().WorkingSet64 / 1024
Allocated Memory: GC.GetTotalMemory(false) / 1024*

Comment: Sorry, but your question is not really clear. What you want to do and why ? You can measure almost everything but your answer should be more specifiy to get help from us.

Comment: Do you want to do this using a tool, or programmatically?

Comment: Added more details to the question. I am doing this programmatically.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use a profiler? They are made for exactly this kind of analysis.

Comment: Why do you think that a method can consume memory by its own? unless you only care of local variables declared inside that method, I think that memory allocated to a method is not very meaningful, cpu usage when methods runs I understand...

Answer (score 0):

Use GC.GetTotalMemory(false) at checkPoint_2_start checkPoint_2_end (or any other function for the metric you need). The additional amount of memory used between those two checkpoints is the value returned at checkPoint_2_end, minus the value returned at checkPoint_2_start.

If you want only the memory usage for a single thread, you cannot do that I think. You would have to track all your allocations somehow.

Use Process.TotalProcessorTime for CPU time.

Comment: Will this work well with the garbage collector? The whole concept of "used memory" is pretty weird when the GC is considered.

Comment: We can think of used memory 3 different ways when using the garbage collector: memory use including garbage (passing false to GetTotalMemory); memory use minus garbage (passing true to GetTotalMemory); memory use of the process, which includes empty memory not used by the garbage collector. For me, memory use minus garbage is the most important measure, as it allows you to compare algorithms in terms of the final result (final memory usage). If you are concerned with locality of data access (faster to reuse same memory areas), total memory allocated by "new" calls may be more important.

Comment: Well, you did use GC.GetTotalMemory(false), so does that means you want the calculation to include garbage?

Comment: I used false as a parameter because you specified that in your question. I would not normally include garbage myself, because it is not an accurate figure -- there may have been an intermediate garbage collection, so you will not get all the garbage included in a determinate way. If you need garbage, you must explicitly track memory allocated to get the best result.